# FileReader readAsBinaryString() to Image DOM Element

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, filereader

If have an input type file

```
<input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
```

and an Image

```
<img id="img">
```

If a file is selected I want to read Exif data from the image an load it into the img tag.

```
var $inputFile = $("#file");

$inputFile.on("change", function() {
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    var files = $inputFile[0].files;

    var reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var file = reader.result;

        // this is not working
        img.src = file;

        var binaryString = reader.result;
        var oFile = new BinaryFile(binaryString, 0, file.size);
        var exif  = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(oFile);

        // read exif data
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(files[0]);
});
```

The problem is that I did not get any image on the screen. It only shows up if I use reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); but this I cannot use because I need the binaryString for the Exif data.

**How do I get the image tag to show the selected file which is a binary string?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to show an image in "binary" form, you need to have it as a base62 encoded string, aka "dataURL".
To use it binary and put it as the src you can make a [ObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL).

```
var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
image.src=objectURL;
```

You don't need a fileReader for this, but you will need fileReader for your exif analysis

Comment: I tried img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file); but it shows an error: Uncaught TypeError: Type error reader.onload

Comment: it accepts a File or a Blob, not a FileReader object. Please refer to the docs

Comment: This does not help how do I get a file or a blob?

Comment: maybe you should read and not guess what parameters a function does expect? This should help you; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications